# How to create POJO from toString method's output

Tags: java

I am building a utility to store failed DB records from original application.
I am printing failed Objects in Log and using this file as input to my utility app.

Input:
"Class01(name="John",age=30,dateModified=2022-09-30)"

Now I want to read this same class from utility, is there any easy way to read this?

Comment: Are you trying to [serialize](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization) and deserialize an object through text?

Comment: Basically yes..

Comment: If you _must_ do something like this (and there are almost always better ways), you'll minimize your headaches if you serialize to JSON.

Comment: I suggest you learn about serializing to XML or JSON, and tools for processing & binding such as Simple framework, Jackson, or implementations of the Jakarta.ee specifications.

Answer (score 0):

Best to serialize to XML or JSON, using tools mentioned in [my Comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74143653/how-to-create-pojo-from-tostring-methods-output/74144338#comment130907039_74143653).

But short of that, here is some quick-and-dirty code.

Beware: This code fails if any name field contains a COMMA character. Thus my advice to use an XML or JSON parsing library.

Parse.

```
String input = "Class01(name=\"John\",age=30,dateModified=2022-09-30)" ;
String[] pairs = input.split( "," ) ;
```

Parse each pair.

```
String name = pairs[ 0 ].replace( "Class01(name=\"" , "" ).replace( "\"" , "" ) ;
int age = Integer.parseInt( pairs[ 1 ].replace( "age=" , "" ) ) ;
LocalDate dateModified = LocalDate.parse( pairs[ 2 ].replace( "dateModified=" , "" ).replace( ")" , "" ) ) ;
```

Define your class.

```
record Class01 ( String name , int age , LocalDate dateModified ) {}
```

Instantiate.

```
Class01 c = new Class01( name , age , dateModified ) ;
```

> c.toString() = Class01[name=John, age=30, dateModified=2022-09-30]

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is: use json lib to serialize the POJO. Examples:

```
class Class01 {
    String name;
    int age;
    String dateModified;
    
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return JSON.toJSONString(this);
    }
}
```

If you wanna parse the output of toString(), just use

```
JSON.parseObject(string, Class01.class);
```

But if your application just need the custom string format like below:

```
Class01(name="John",age=30,dateModified=2022-09-30)
```

Only way is defined a rule parser, but it seems very complicated. Finally I think any split/replace/substring etc operation is unsafe. Because the value may contain the split char or replace char.